# How to Get a List of Sub Blogs without Using get_blog_list()?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

The `get_blog_list()` function has been deprecated from v3.0. How does one get a list of blogs in a multisite blog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trac has some discussion and code for possible replacement in future version, ticket [#14511 new function - wp_get_sites($args)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14511).

Comment: Until the future release we don't have an alternative to get_blog_list()?

Comment: Correct. As far as I know there is currently no native function for this, [`get_blog_list()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_list) says _No alternative available._

Comment: Correct. you'll have to use it until it is replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You could directly query your database.

```
global $wpdb;

$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs ORDER BY blog_id" );
```

This will return an array containing all your sites on the network, you can then use a foreach statement to build & populate your own array.

Also remember to carefully read the [codex page on interfacing with the WP database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) when using `$wpdb` particularly pay attention to the [`$wpdb->prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) method when doing more advanced queries.

Comment: +1 as it _FIXES_ stuff. Even if not pretty, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possibly useful alternative is [get_blogs_of_user($user_id)](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blogs_of_user).

It provides a perfect alternative, but only if all blogs have been created by the same (admin) user - which works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for this like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-recent-posts-widget/.

I've used a similar plugin (derivative of the plugin above) code (original source no longer available, hence no link, only found it two weeks ago as well!) to create a Multisite sitemap Page template that lists the most recent 300 new multisites.

You can download my Page template at www.google-adsense-templates.co.uk/seo-plugin/sitemap-multisite.zip will only work with the Talian 05 SEO theme, but you could easily copy the relevant code to your own themes Page template.

David